# Remapping key combinations (custom macros in linux)

Tags: linux, gnome, macros, x-server, gnome3

I'm not sure at which layer this functionality would have to exist, so I'm just tagging this for my own stack.

In my specific case, I'd really like to map the [Function Key]-J key combination to the down arrow, [Function Key]-K combination to the up arrow on my laptop -- in other words, pressing Fn-J would simulate the down arrow being pressed. I'm running Arch+Gnome3.

I guess xkeycaps can't do key-combos. I know you can do custom mappings to various actions in Gnome, but can't re-map keys in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is [Autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) - key-mapping software similar to [Authohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You use [xmodmap](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/X11/xmodmap.html), which maps keys in Linux, and xev, which traps key events and prints to the screen.  Xev will let you see the mappings for each key pressed.

You will need to change the .xmodmap file, it should be in your home directory. If not there you create one or you can find it in /etc/x11, however, altering this file will change the system for every user.

Good luck.

Comment: I tried xmodmap (via xkeycaps) and it doesn't seem to allow for key combos, unless I missed something.

Comment: Or at least it doesn't allow for key-combos on a laptop's Funciton key (thinkpad T410s). After digging around for a few days, I think I might be out of luck.

Comment: @Aron, what about [Authokeys](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/)?

Comment: doesn't support Fn, but it looks really good anyway. But I think this answers my original question well enough. Do you want to add that as a separate answer and I'll mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Aron, Will do.  cheers.